# PyCharm Community DB console does not output table' content

Tags: sql, pycharm

My PyCharm IDE is something wrong. Select SQL statement does not output table's content in SQLite DB. It is outputed like `'[STRING]'`

Of course table has contents.

Is it because of Community Edition (2017.3)? If it is I don't know why JetBrains made DB console menu in community edition.

[image: result]

Comment: are you *positive* that those aren't actual the values in the database? have you checked it in another application?

Comment: Yes. it is ouputed in DBeaver. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not a PyCharm user ... but that does not look like Database tool window that other JetBrains IDEs have. At first glance it looks like you may have installed some another (3rd party) DB plugin (e.g. Database Navigator).

Comment: Are you sure you're in the correct schema? Result set is of just 1 row - is that the number of rows you were expecting?

Comment: Thank you for answering. I did not add any other 3rd party DB plugin for Pycharm CE. And, It is correct that there is just 1 row because I created only one user.

Comment: It seems that I installed Database Navigator for Pycharm CE.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong. Double check if your screenshot is from Community Edition - I am not able (in the newest 2017.3.2 Community Edition) to do what you showed.

(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> or `Help | Find Action...` from the menu, writing `sql` in the search field:

> No matches found

in the Community Edition, but *lots of matches* in the Professional Edition.

From the [JetBrains site](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/) (see the last row in the comparison table):

[image: Comparison of edition]

**Edit:**

You told in comments that you use [Database Navigator](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1800-database-navigator) plugin. So I installed it into [Pycharm Community Edition 2017.3.2](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=windows) and tried in with [chinook SQLite Sample Database](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-sample-database/) with no problems, so I'm not able to reproduce your problem:

[image]

Comment: Thanks.
Refer to next pages.
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1800-database-navigator

Comment: I tried it with this plugin with no problem - see the end of my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you. I tested with 'chinook SQLite Sample' and also succeeded.

Comment: I was testing with minitwit — a twitter clone(http://github.com/pallets/flask/tree/master/examples/minitwit/) which is flask example at http://flask.pocoo.org, I think it's source's problem creating sqlite DB, but DBeaver tool correctly ouput the sqlite DB's table content.